# api.ipify.org api is always retuening a error

Tags: javascript, json, api

i am working on a ip address js bookmarklet but when ever i use it i use `8.8.8.8` as test ip it always returns `{"code":422,"messages":"Input correct IPv4 or IPv6 address."}` my api key is valid i have filured out but nothing else is *lines 13-15 were added for debugging porpuses

```js
const Http = new XMLHttpRequest();

var ip = prompt("please put the ip here")
var url = "https://geo.ipify.org/api/v1?apiKey=working_api_key&ipAddress=" + ip
alert(url)
if(ip = null){
  alert("confused face")
}else{
  var httpresp = Http.open("GET", url)
  if(httpresp = "{\"code\":422,\"messages\":\"Input correct IPv4 or IPv6 address.\"}"){
    alert("invalid ipAddress")
    alert("fail info url:" + url)
    alert("ip:" + ip)
    alert("httpresp:" + httpresp)
  }else{
    alert("Done: found ip info for (" + ip + ")")
    alert(httpresp)
  }
}
```

Comment: If the URL really does look right I think you'll have to ask ipify directly for help. Can you make the requests work in a browser, is it just this script? Can you make an account balance request with your API key to check it?

Comment: `=` is assignment, `==` is comparing.

Comment: TYSM so much i did not know that

Comment: @Evert now the second `alert(httpresp)` is not working :/ returns `undefined`

Comment: According to the documentation, XMLHttpRequest.open does indeed not return anything, so this is expected: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest/open